# Apple iPad apple-mobile-web-app-capable caching issue

Tags: ipad, iphone-web-app

I have created a web app for the iPad and have set the following tag:

`<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />`

I am not using a manifest file because I don't want to use offline yet the iPad seems to cache it anyway.

I have had to reset the iPad to clear this cache, is there another way to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS files should be refreshed every time you start your app. Most problems appear with JavaScript calls. To solve that:
In your  tag, add a parameter with a timestamp in your programming language, for example with php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javacsript.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

That worked for me. If you still have problems with your CSS files, try to do the same with those tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

I haven't tried this one though.